# Display an image stored in MySql database in BLOB format using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using the following function to store image in db

```
 void SaveImage(byte[] image)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(db);//new connection is made
            con.Open();

                string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Picture(RoomNo ,pic )VALUES ('" + RoomNo.Text + "',?Image)";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Image", image);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         
        }
```

In main I am calling the function like this

```
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                picbox.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                SaveImage(ms.ToArray());
            }
```

I do not know how to display it in a picture box .. can any one help me???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Windows Forms? And you must Convert Byte array to Image for displaying it in Picture Box.

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

And how did you convert Image to byte array. I hope that problem not there. You can use:

```
  private byte[] ImageToByteArray(string ImageFile)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(
              ImageFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

        // Convert image to byte array.
        byte[] photo = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

        return photo;
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply but i got some doubt am storing pic in db as BLOB format,how do i bring that value to my form and how do i call this functions when i click one button?

Comment: First of all you must convert blob data to byte array. And then you will call the method byteArrayToImage. Something like this:
picbox.Image = byteArrayToImage(blobData.ToByteArray).
If it helped +1 my answer. Thanks.

Comment: am retriving blob data like this....pic = dr["Pic"].ToString(); and calling the methods like      byte[]array = new byte[150];
            array = ImageToByteArray(pic);
            picturebox.Image = byteArrayToImage(array); ... its not working ..can you pls help me..

Comment: Thanks @Farhad Jabiyev... its working.. +10 for your answer..to convert the blob data into byte array i used this code  Byte[] byteBLOBData = (Byte[])(dr["pic"]);.....

Comment: I am glad @SeD. But if you'll +1 my answer, i ll be glad more. ;)

Answer (score 0):

set your image picture box using Image method (FromStream)

```
  yourPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```